# Where to put my volume pedals

Tags: effects-pedal

I have a guitar processor. I'm happy with everything it does inside it. I want to use a volume pedal outside of the one in the processor because it's terrible.

Where would I put an outside volume pedal to just allow the processor to do what it is doing now. In other words just control the volume of the processor itself. Not affect anything in the order of what the processor is doing now.

Comment: Sorry I was reading a volume pedal issue that someone else posted. that's why it started off with I have a similiar question. :)

Comment: Is it not a possibility to put the internal volume pedal anywhere in the chain?

Answer (score 5):

It isn't wrong to do it either way. You should try it both ways and put your setup through the paces to see which you like best.

If you put the volume pedal first, it will act like the volume knob on your guitar. This means that your overdriven sounds will be affected, giving you cleaner sounds when the volume pedal is low.

Since you say "... just control the volume of the processor itself. Not affect anything in the order of what the processor is doing now," you will probably prefer to put the volume pedal *after* your effects processor. This will act more like a master volume, just changing the volume level of the processed sound.